# Should i REBUILD or REORGANIZE indexes after deleting all the data from a table

Tags: database, sqlite

I have indexed over a table, at some point user has the option to empty the table `DELETE FROM [Table];`.

Questions, should I `REBUILD` or `REORGANIZE` the Indexes after removing all the data and adding new ones. If yes which one should I do `REBUILD` or `REORGANIZE`?

Answer (score 0):

You should use neither one, because there is no REBUILD or REORGANIZE statement in [SQLite's SQL language](http://www.sqlite.org/lang.html).

The [REINDEX documentation](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_reindex.html) says:

> This is useful when the definition of a collation sequence has changed.

The FTS [rebuild command](http://www.sqlite.org/fts3.html#*fts4rebuidcmd) is similar:

> The "rebuild" command should be run whenever the implementation of a custom tokenizer changes, so that all content can be retokenized. The "rebuild" command is also useful when using the [FTS4 content option](http://www.sqlite.org/fts3.html#*fts4content) after changes have been made to the original content table.